# Image gallery like https://www.pexels.com/ with bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css

Hi im trying to make an image gallery like https://www.pexels.com/ with bootstrap 4, but bootstrap doesn't arrange the pictures like i want.

html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <img src="imgsource" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
img{
   width: 100%;
}
```

my result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhrCL.jpg)

Comment: The Bootstrap grid system isn't built to provide the custom layout that you want. You'd have to code it manually or possibly use a JavaScript plugin of some sort.

Comment: So far you have done absolutely nothing to advance towards your goal, which means you are expecting us to work for you for free. It's pretty much like saying: I made a website for a client. Now I have another client and I want the site made for the first one to change itself into the site for the second one. Here's the website for the first client. Please edit your question with code that, in your opinion, should produce the result you expect. Please also update with any resource/documentation that made you believe your code should work.

Comment: the most help you would get from this. `float: left`

Answer (score 0):

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Gallery</title>

   <style>
ul {list-style: none}
 </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="row">
        <ul>
            <!-- first row  -->
            <li class="col-md-6"><img src=""></li>
            <li class="col-md-2"><img src=""></li>
            <li class="col-md-2"><img src=""></li>
            <li class="col-md-2"><img src=""></li>
            <!-- second row -->
            <li class="col-md-5"><img src=""></li>
            <li class="col-md-5"><img src=""></li>
            <li class="col-md-2"><img src=""></li>
            <!-- third row -->
        </ul> 
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html> 

  Height of the image must be same but width can vary. 
  Total screen contains 12 columns. According to the style choose the 
  column size.
```

Answer (score 0):

I never tried using bootstrap but I have built by myself using flex box. Try this below code:

html:

```
<div class="photos" id="photoContainer">
  <div class="photos__columns">
    <div class="holders" id="0">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="photos__columns">
    <div class="holders" id="1">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="photos__columns">
    <div class="holders" id="2">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

scss:

```
.photos {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
  &__columns {
    display: block;
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }

  .holders {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    .images {
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      height: auto;
    }
  }
}
```

[Click to see the demo in my codepen](https://codepen.io/sajanv88/pen/pYNrZj)

Answer (score -1):

add this to your

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/masonry-layout@4.2.2/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js" integrity="sha384-GNFwBvfVxBkLMJpYMOABq3c+d3KnQxudP/mGPkzpZSTYykLBNsZEnG2D9G/X/+7D" crossorigin="anonymous" async></script>
```

and also add this

```
data-masonry='{"percentPosition": true }'
```

to your div like this:

```
<div class = "row" data-masonry='{"percentPosition": true }'></div>
```